# Date picker showing local time settings

Tags: swift, datepicker

I need to show am pm in my date picker. And I did the code and works well. If i changed time settings in my iPhone to 24 hours format, the code is crashed.

```
let timeObject = CodeSnippets.getDateFromISOTimeWithDateFormat(labelTimeValue.text!, format: "hh : mm a")!
```

and the method defined is

```
class func getDateFromISOTimeWithDateFormat(dateString : NSString,format: String) -> NSDate?
{
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    let enUSPosixLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.locale = enUSPosixLocale
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format

    return dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString as String)
}
```

I want to show am pm as per design in my picker. I

Answer (score 0):

If you want to how the AM/PM you use

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"
```

Comment: the "a" is what gives you the AM/PM....there is a whole bunch of things you can do like h:mm or mm:ss for seconds.....theres also shortcuts like Shortstyle (i dont have the list in front of me)